# Environment Variables in App Engine for local dev

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

What's the best way to set environment variables when developing nodejs on a local machine for App Engine Flex environment? If they're set in app.yaml then they don't get set during local development. Is there a way to force this, or should I use something like dotenv and keep track of the same environment variables in 2 places?

Answer (score 4):

Sensitive data (e.g. API Keys) should not be committed to source code.

The way I went around that is storing a `.env` file in Google Storage. Then you can use `@google-cloud/storage` to download it in production (using a `prestart` hook) and [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to load variables into memory.

You may find a full guide here: http://gunargessner.com/gcloud-env-vars/

---

PS: I would go for Aidan's answer for storing any data that is not sensitive. I have myself used `dotenv` satisfactorily in the past.
Similar to that, there's [nconf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nconf), the package that `gcloud` itself [uses for examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/81df6cc75ce7bb4f73829d52b1b138819d8947e2/appengine/parse-server/server.js#L24). Pretty neat!

Comment: This is great! The only thing I would add is instead of verbosely declaring the environment variable `production` on this line `const dsKey = ds.key(['ENV_VAR', 'production'])` use the `NODE_ENV` variable. So that line now looks like this `const dsKey = ds.key(['ENV_VAR', process.env.NODE_ENV])` This way you can place all your config files there by just having two keys(development and production).

Comment: Thanks, @GarrettTacoronte. I agree, but now I've updated the answer to use a much simpler alternative. You should check it out!

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

`require('dotenv').config({path: '/custom/project/root/app.yaml'})`

**Option 2:**

Maintain both a .env file and a .yaml file with the same keys but different values (local and GAE, respectively). In app.yaml, I make sure not to deploy my .env file by adding the following line:

`skip_files : .env`

You will then need to add a check on ('dotenv').config() to make sure that it doesn't error or overwrite your process variables if no .env file is detected.

Answer (score 0):

Aidan's suggestion is good.

As configurations *should* be different on GAE and local, I would suggest option 2 is best - a separate `.ENV` for local and `.YAML` for GAE environments.

One minor point though. I'd suggest to add a `.gcloudignore` files, something like the below:

```
.gcloudignore
.git
.gitignore
.env
staging.yaml
node_modules/
```